# Pyramiding only when PnL is positive

Tags: pine-script

quick question. Regarding pyramiding orders in pine strategies, I would like to have the second and subsequent orders go through only if the current PnL is positive. Is there a workaround for this in pine? I cannot come up with any ideas. I don't need the exact code, just please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = 10)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if strategy.position_size > 0 and  strategy.openprofit < 0 and longCondition
    longCondition := false
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if strategy.position_size > 0 and  strategy.openprofit < 0 and shortCondition
    shortCondition := false
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction. I ended up implementing it like this:  
`notLongAndLosing = not (strategy.position_size > 0 and  strategy.openprofit < 0)
notShortAndLosing = not (strategy.position_size < 0 and  strategy.openprofit < 0)

longcondition = Long and VolumeCondition and notLongAndLosing
shortcondition = Short and VolumeCondition and notShortAndLosing`